# How to use Pivot Point in Transformations

Tags: opengl, glsl

How to translate object using Center point

I have a rectangle which has a center point away from the position of rectangle.

when i rotate rectangle it rotates around its center axis.

if i multyply position before rotation in the modelView matrix

```
ModelViewMatrix = Rotation * Scaling * Position
```

Suppose if i want to do these translations.

1) Translate the rectangle position by x = 10 units.

1) Rotate the rectangle  by 35 degree with the center point at the center of the rectangle.

2) Translate the rectangle position by x = 10 units.

3) change the x position of the center point by 10 units( rectangle should not be affected by the change in the center point position)

[image]4) Now rotate the rectangle using the new center point.

If someone could please guide me how do we use Center point in transformations. 
How do i build by ModelView Matrix if i am using a center Point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to following rectangle, where the red cross is the center of the world and you want to rotate it around the green pivot

[image]

then you've to do the following steps:

- Translate the rectangle in that way that way, that the pivot is on the origin of the world. This is a translation by the vector form the pivot to the origin.

[image]

- Rotate the rectangle

[image]

- Translate the rectangle in that way that the pivot is back at its original position. This is a translation by the vector form the origin to the pivot.

[image]

In the following `transPivot` is a translation matrix, which is defined by the vector from the origin (0, 0) to the pivot point (`pivotPos`). The pivot is marked by the green cross.
`rotation` is the rotation matrix around the z-axis:

```
ModelViewMatrix = transPivot * rotation * -transPivot
```

`-transPivot` is the `inverse(transPivot)` matrix, which is equal the translation matrix by `-pivotPos` in this case.