# glm rotation in ortho space

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I set up my ortho projection like this :

```
transform = glm::ortho(0.0f, width, height, 0.0f);
```

this works pretty well, but when I want to use the `glm::rotate` function like this:

```
transform = glm::rotate(transform, glm::radians(45.0f), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
```

my object rotates around 0 : 0 : 0.

my vertices look like this:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    600, 100, 0,
    612, 100, 0,
    612, 130, 0,
    600, 130, 0
};
```

how can I make my object rotate around its center ?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:glm] tag. [tag:glm] (generalized linear models) != [tag:glm-math] (GLM - OpenGL Mathematics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rotate around its center you have to:

- Translate the object so that the center of the object is moved to (0, 0).
- Rotate the object.
- Move the object so that the center point moves in its original position.

```cpp
GLfloat center_x = 606.0f;
GLfloat center_y = 115.0f;

transform = glm::translate(transform, glm::vec3(center_x, center_y, 0));
transform = glm::rotate(transform, glm::radians(45.0f), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
transform = glm::translate(transform, glm::vec3(-center_x, -center_y, 0));
```

See also [How to use Pivot Point in Transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56804658/how-to-use-pivot-point-in-transformations/56806370#56806370)